# How do I use PG_restore to backup/move my DB?

Tags: postgresql, centos

I am fairly new with PQSQL and am slowly picking things up - I have added a new disk and would like to do two things:

1. Restore a backup to this new disk - /hda2/pgdata/
2. Move a database from /hda1/pgdata to /hda2/pgdata/

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Use pg_restore to restore a database. Check out the documentation which is very clear.

One important thing to remember, if you want to move to a later version of PostgreSQL use the later version of pg_dump to create a backup dump file. For example if you want to move from PostgreSQL version 8.3 to version 8.4, then create a backup dump file using pg_dump from version 8.4 and then use pg_restore 8.4 to recreate database in the 8.4 server.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgrestore.html

Q2. Backup and restore is a safe way of doing it. Before restoring one can create a tablespace on the new disk and place the database in that space.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb TABLESPACE myspace;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple command to restore database

1. Open PSQL Command console
2. Provide credentials
3. go to specific database that you need to restore (If the dataabse is not there Create empty database

`/i < sql Dump file Path >   e.g. \i /usr/local/pgsql/db20121109.sql`