# How to create a table under different Databases in Psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, create-table

I have 2 databases in my PSQL and I want to create a table in a particular schema.

Example:

I have database **test1 /schema b** and **test2 / schema c/d**

I want to create a new table in **test2 database** under **schema d**

Because of installation setup my default database is test1.

Comment: what tool do you want to use to create that table, or if you want to do it from code, what language?

Answer (score 8):

In order to create a new table in test2, you should first connect to **test2 database**.  Then you can specify the **d schema** in the creation sentence:

```
CREATE TABLE d.tableName (...)
```

Check [CREATE TABLE documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain which type of installation you are using 
 GUI based or a console version
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

1. If you have GUI you can simply right click and create new table `Table Name , Columns and data type`
2. If you have console based version you need to login and go into particular database which you are going to create table 
   If you need complete code Please do let me know I'll post the complete code for that

Comment: I was using SQL shell and got the way to connect the different Database and create the table usder the Schema                                                               \connect database database_name;                                                     create table table name (field);

Comment: [I informed you yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244846/237838); please do not include a 'signature' in your posts. Your user box already serves as that.